Stuttering Audio After Fresh 24.04 Install
After a fresh install of 24.04 Desktop yesterday, some audio and video files I played along with some streaming were fine but today after some updates any audio stutters badly. I see that this has been reported as a bug but I have not found a workaround for my own system.
My system's audio is through the headphone jack of the LG display to external powered speakers and the monitors themselves are connected via HDMI. Any workaround or fix? installing pulseaudio did not help.
My playback devices are as follows:
# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev3 Analog [ALC662 rev3 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [LG FULL HD]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [SAMSUNG]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

My ALSA information has been uploaded here.

No fix for this even though 24.04 has been out for a while? Audio is totally useless and unlistenable as it is.

After every update I try the audio again but still totally unusable. I've never seen an Ubuntu bug that remained for so long! Is anyone working in it and what is the ETA for repair? It worked fine before upgrading to 24.04.

try this work around. access the GPU GRUB. most new computers use the escape key, when powering up rapidly press the escape key until the grub menu appears. using the down arrow key select Advanced options for ubuntu and hit enter. using the down arrow key select Ubuntu, with linx 6.1.109-0601109-generic and hit enter. this will boot you into an older kernal that still works with hdmi. you will have to boot this way until the issue is resolved.If this kernal doesn't exist someone with more experience than me will have to help you with reinstalling the older kernal.
this may have happened because ubuntu only saves 3 older kernals, every time you update softwear that has a new kernal in it ubuntu pops the oldest kernal off the list. If the desired kernal is at the bottom you may want to wait until your sure ubuntu has corrected the issue before updating softwear.

This was a fresh install so no previous kernels available. I am, however, looking for a fix, not a kludge.

I understand, I'm hopping they correct the problem asap. You did mention a workaround in your initial texts thats why I submitted my workaround. As an extra help if you get tired of waiting for the fix the mainline softwear included with ubuntu instalation will allow you to add the missing kernal, just to get you by. good luck with your quest.

Yes, I mentioned workaround in my original comment when 24.04 was new while giving time for the issue to be fixed but there is no excuse now to have to go that route!

I can't believe that this has STILL not been fixed! Multimedia is what I do so as long as this issue continues, Ubuntu is useless to me.

Try connecting a different audio output such as bluetooth. That worked for me. Obv a workaround..

Not an answer to the question asked.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

I don’t have a different audio output available. The only one is the headphone jack on one of the displays which themselves are HDMI. This has always worked well until 24.04.

What part of 'workaround' did y'all not understand?
